# jQuery count characters and add class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use jQuery to count how many characters are in, for example, an `<li>`, and if the amount is greater than XX characters, apply a class to that element?

I've seen plenty of jQuery character counters (ie http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/character-counter), and I can see how `.addClass()` would handle that part of things, but am having some trouble putting it together.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Many thanks

**THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE ANSWERS - Found one solution that works for me as indicated below**

Comment: You might want to update your question as some code was clearly stripped out and it's unclear what you want.

Comment: you can use .text() and then count characters right...///

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// The number of characters
var XX = 100;

$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > XX;
}).addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not select your `<li>` element into a variable and get its length?

```
var length = $('li').html().length;
```

From here, just check if the value on length is greater than the value you're comparing to and use .addClass()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a specific li item (instead of all li elements in your page) you can give it an ID :

```
<li id="myli">...</li>
```

Then if you want to execute your code at page load do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yourElement = $('#myli');
    var charLength = yourElement.text().length;
    if(charLength > xx){
       yourElement.addClass('yourClass');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the amount of characters in a string by doing this a.length, where a is a string.

```
$('a').each(function(){
 if($(this).text().length > XX){
  $(this).addClass('someClass');
 }
});
```