# input field width set to content

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

So I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSBYG/9/embedded/result/). I have two jquery ui plugins witch gives these two input fields values. So the user is not ment to edit the fields manually therefore they are set to readonly.

Now to the problem, is there a way for me to change the width of the input fields dependent of the content size? Setting just the width in css to say 300px or so will maybe work for Septemember, but if the user choses some other month like May then it needs to be alot less then 300px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/SSBYG/30/

What I did is to count all the characters and then set the width based on the results

```
date.style.width = (date.value.length * 7) + "px";
time.style.width = (time.value.length * 7) + "px";
```

**Note:** if you are going to use that a lot and not just 2 times, it will be good idea to make a function

This is also useful: [jQuery count characters and add class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378871/jquery-count-charecters-and-add-class)

Answer (score 0):

The `size` attribute of the `input` html tag of type `text` is meant to specify the visible width in characters.
Thus

```
function adjust_width(element) {
    element.size=element.value.length;
}
adjust_width($('#date')[0]);
adjust_width($('#time')[0]);
```

should do the trick with your example.

Comment: adding this to the jsfiddle did not do anything

Comment: @halliewuud I guess because that jsfiddle included mootools but not jQuery. I wrote my example for jQuery since you mention you use it on your page. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/SSBYG/29/

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only size the input to approximate width of that many characters in the given font. Try strings with exceptionally wide or thin characters: `value="WWWWWW"` or `value="llllll"`.