# How can I change the size of my text on a mobile device?

Tags: css, wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile, font-size

I know how to use the (font-size) attribute, but  I only want the letters on a mobile device to get smaller when the letters reach a certain amount.....

When letters reach 40 characters, I want the letters to shrink so that it can fit in a mobile browser

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes it can be done. You can use media queries to apply certain CSS styles only to certain screen sizes, in addition to the more dubious method of using User Agent strings to detect how users are accessing your site. Alternatively, you can simply use responsive values like `em` or `rem` rather than `px` to achieve appropriate font-sizes with relation to the rest of your site.

Comment: @TylerH -  I want the text to only adjust when It gets to a certain length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to count the number of caracters inside a certain tag. For instance in a `<p>`like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dL1zzdtg/1/

```
var XX = 40;

$('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > XX;
}).addClass('long_paragraph');
```

You adjust the number of caracters in the XX = 40 above.

and in the css add:

```
p.long_paragraph {font-size:70%;}
```

[image]

(I found the javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378871/jquery-count-characters-and-add-class) )

Comment: What exactly does this do?

Comment: This counts the number of characters inside each `<p>`on your site, and adds a CSS class if, and only if, there are more characters than 40 inside the `<p>`.  Then in your CSS file you need to add the styling that you want to take effect if there is more than 40 characters inside the tag.

Comment: You must also use `@media`in your css if you only want this to take effect on mobiles/ small screens.

Comment: @chrishughes See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dL1zzdtg/3/ I have added a media query for all screens less than 500 px. Try to resize the window and see how it takes effect when the window is less than 500 px wide. (Where you see the HTML output)

Comment: Are you not understanding what I am telling you??!! @Preben

Comment: I think so. And I have given you the exact solution I believe you need. You have not provided any code, but the solution above will work if you apply it right.